# Asks for claims again when identityserver restarts

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4, claims-based-identity

I just cloned identityserver following repo.

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4

and I changed following class to bring data from the database instead of in-memory users and inserted as well when new added.

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/dev/src/IdentityServer4/Test/TestUserStore.cs

But it asks for claims again when I restart Identityserver even if I have granted claims before restart(and also stored in the database). But if I don't restart then it works properly (redirects back to my home page as expected if claims are granted already)

so what extra do I need to do apart from this TestUserStore.cs method changes to bring data from the database instead of user store?

Answer (score 0):

I thought everything was getting stored in token. But grant also required to persist. I got it through following article.

https://mcguirev10.com/2018/01/02/identityserver4-without-entity-framework.html